# Disable JSTREE check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Just curious to know if there is any way in JSTREE to disable checkbox?

I basically need to disable(not deselect) all my selected child nodes when I click on the parent node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new type(disabled) for this. It can be done as follows

```
   "types" : {
        "types": {
        "disabled" : { 
              "check_node" : false, 
              "uncheck_node" : false 
            } 
        }
    }
```

and then assign that type as

```
.set_type("disabled", "#node5");
```

More [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) is here.

For disabling all child nodes, create an event handler for the change_state event

```
$("#treeElement").bind("change_state.jstree", function (e, d) {
    var node = d.args[0];
    // here disable all child nodes
    }
});
```

Comment: Would this be helpful to disable to checboxes of child nodes when selecting the parent node?

Comment: You have to bind change_event and then disable all its children. Check my update

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I need to set this type. Is `$("#treeElement").set_type("disabled", "#node");` correct to be inserted in the change state event handler?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/U46JH/
Can you have a look at this fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, I had just copied and pasted the .js file I am working with.

Comment: And.. congrats on reaching 1k reputation! :)

Comment: I'm not using JSP/HTML in my project. All inputs are supplied by java program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23090/discussion-between-lgap-and-wolf)

Comment: Hi, I'm desperately looking for the solution would you please tell me where to put the set_type function. I would be extremely thankful